# Unexpected output while reading a CSV file using PHP

Tags: php

I am reading a comma separated csv file line by line using a php script. Everything working fine however in my output i see that an integer value 1 gets printed at the end of the array, not sure were that is coming from ? I check my csv file it does not have a 1 any where ?

```
<?php
$f_pointer=fopen("readme.csv","r"); // file pointer

while(! feof($f_pointer)){
$ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);

echo print_r($ar[0]);
echo " "; 
echo print_r($ar[1]);

echo "\n";
}
?>
```

readCsv.csv

```
bi-crossman-prod-251.services.joo.member.net,198.11.241.3
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `echo print_r(...)`... [print_r()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) returns a boolean true, which you're then echoing (and a Boolean trues echoes as `1`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this insead. You don't need to `echo` `print_r` as it already prints the array for you.

```
<?php
$f_pointer=fopen("readme.csv","r"); // file pointer

while(! feof($f_pointer)){
   $ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);

    print_r($ar[0]);
    echo "<br>"; 
    print_r($ar[1]);

    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only **echo** instead **print_r**

```
echo $ar[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$f_pointer=fopen("readme.csv","r"); // file pointer

while(! feof($f_pointer)){
 $ar = fgetcsv($f_pointer);
 echo $ar[0]." ".$ar[1]."\n";
}

fclose($f_pointer);
?>
```